# Regex to find string containing 5-8 digits and at least 1 occurences of the underscore "_" character

Tags: regex

I need a regex to find all the strings containing between 5-8 digits and at least 1 occurences of '_' or more.
This is an example :

```
123456_123456 --> YES
12345678_12345678_12345678 --> YES
123456_12345678_123456_12345678 --> YES
12345_123456_1234567_12345678_ --> YES

123456_1 --> NO
123456_12 --> NO
123456_1594126781 --> NO (timestamp at the end)
123_1594126781 --> NO (timestamp at the end)
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please do add what you tried and why it didn't worked out for you.

Comment: Is  example #4 correct with a trailing underscore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trailing `_` on the 4th valid sample seems a bit strange. I'm assuming you'd only ever want that on the very end. Therefor a pattern like the following may work for you:

```
^(?=.*_)\d{5,8}(?:_\d{5,8})*_?$
```

See the online demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/vr2rJh/4).

Note that this would also validate `12345_` since it would have *"at least 1 occurences of '_' or more."*. If that is not what you meant you could change the `*` quantifier into a `+` and remove the positive lookahead:

```
^\d{5,8}(?:_\d{5,8})+_?$
```

See the online demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/vr2rJh/6)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your 2 solutions ! My tries was far away from your solution... I'm going to use your second approach to be sure my specific code is not executed for "12345_". Thanks again, Regex is not my strong suit...

Answer (score 3):

You may also try:

```
^(?:\d{5,8}_)+\d{5,8}_?$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`^, $`** - Represents start and end of line respectively.
- **`(?:\d{5,8}_)+`** - Represents non-capturing group matching digits 5 to 8 times along with an `_` and the whole pattern repeats one or more time.
- **`\d{5,8}_?`** - Matches digits 5 to 8 times with an optional `_`.

---

[image]

#### Regex Demo

Comment: Yes it works too including "12345_" ;) Thanks for that suggestion and explaination !

Comment: I updated my answer @JonathanRIO; please check now